# Characteristic Property of the Orientation Covering (Problem 15-10 in Lee's Smooth Manifolds book)

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, covering-spaces, orientation

**The problem statement:**

> Let $M$ be a connected nonorientable smooth manifold with or without boundary, and let $\widehat{\pi}: \widehat{M} \to M$ be its orientation covering. Prove that if $X$ is any oriented smooth manifold with or without boundary, and $F: X \to M$ is any local diffeomorphism, then there exists a unique orientation-preserving local diffeomorphism $\widehat{F}: X \to \widehat{M}$ such that $\widehat{\pi} \circ \widehat{F} = F$.

**My attempt:**

I defined the map as $\widehat{F}(p) = \left(F(p), \left[dF_p(E_1), ..., dF_p(E_n)\right]\right)$ where $(E_1, ..., E_n)$ is any oriented basis for $T_pX$. Since $F$ is a local diffeomorphism, $\left(dF_p(E_1), ..., dF_p(E_n)\right)$ is a basis for $T_{F(p)}M$, and if $(E_1', ..., E_n')$ is another oriented basis for $T_pX$ then the transition matrix relating $\left(dF_p(E_1'), ..., dF_p(E_n')\right)$ to $\left(dF_p(E_1), ..., dF_p(E_n)\right)$ is the same as the transition matrix relating $(E_1', ..., E_n')$ to $(E_1, ..., E_n)$ so it has positive determinant and the orientations determined by these bases are the same. So $\widehat{F}$ is well-defined.

It's clear from the construction that $\widehat{\pi} \circ \widehat{F} = F$.

I want to show that $\widehat{F}$ is a local diffeomorphism.

First pick a smooth chart $(U, \varphi)$ for $X$ containing $p$. Since $F$ is a local diffeomorphism, we may assume that $F\vert_U: U \to F(U)$ is a diffeomorphism onto an open subset $F(U)$ of $M$ (after possibly shrinking $U$). Shrinking $U$ again if necessary, we may also assume that $F(U)$ is evenly covered by $\widehat{\pi}$. Then $\left(F(U), \varphi \circ (F\vert_U)^{-1}\right)$ is a smooth chart for $M$ containing $F(p)$. Also if $V$ is the component of $\widehat{\pi}^{-1}(F(U))$ containing $\widehat{F}(p)$, then $\left(V, \varphi \circ (F\vert_U)^{-1} \circ \widehat{\pi}\vert_V\right)$ is a smooth chart for $\widehat{M}$ containing $\widehat{F}(p)$.

Since $F(U)$ is evenly covered, it must be connected so $U$ is also connected (consequence of the definition of evenly covered used in the book, or else we could just choose $U$ to be connected already). Then **if we already know that $\widehat{F}$ is continuous**, $\widehat{F}(U)$ is a connected subset of $\widehat{\pi}^{-1}\left(F(U)\right)$ containing $\widehat{F}(p)$ so $\widehat{F}(U) \subseteq V$.

The coordinate representation of $\widehat{F}$ with respect to the smooth charts defined above is $$\left(\varphi \circ (F\vert_U)^{-1} \circ \widehat{\pi}\vert_V\right)\circ\widehat{F}\circ\varphi^{-1} = \varphi \circ (F\vert_U)^{-1} \circ (\widehat{\pi}\circ\widehat{F})\vert_U\circ\varphi^{-1}$$ $$ = \varphi \circ (F\vert_U)^{-1} \circ F\vert_U\circ\varphi^{-1} = \text{id}_{\varphi(U)}$$
And this is enough to show that $\widehat{F}$ is a local diffeomorphism.

But I can't really prove that $\widehat{F}$ is continuous or to prove in any other way that $\widehat{F}(U) \subseteq V$. I'm probably missing something trivial or looking at it the wrong way.

Comment: Can anyone please explain why nonorientability is required?

Comment: @5Somebody I might be wrong, but I don't think nonorientability is required. At least my proof didn't seem to assume nonorientability of $M$.

If $M$ is orientable, then $\widehat{M}$ has two components, each diffeomorphic to $M$, but you can define $\widehat{F}$ as above anyway. And there is only one possible definition because if you chose $\widehat{F}(p) = (F(p), -[dF_p(E_1), ..., dF_p(E_n)])$ instead, then $d\hat{\pi}_{\hat{F}(p)} \circ d\widehat{F}_p = dF_p$ would not be orientation-preserving with the orientation $-[dF_p(E_1), ..., dF_p(E_n)]$ on its codomain.

Comment: (Since the orientation on $\widehat{M}$ is defined so that $d\hat{\pi}_{(p, \mathcal{O}_p)}: T_{(p, \mathcal{O}_p)}\widehat{M} \to T_pM$ is orientation-preserving when using the pointwise orientation $\mathcal{O}_p$ on its codomain, we would need to use $-[dF_p(E_1), ..., dF_p(E_n)]$ as the orientation for $T_pM$ when defining the orientation on $T_{(p, \mathcal{O}_p)}\widehat{M}$ that makes $d\hat{\pi}_{\hat{F}(p)}$ orientation-preserving. Also by assumption $d\widehat{F}_p$ is orientation-preserving, so their composition should be orientation-preserving, but it clearly isn't.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not need to show that $\hat F$ is continuous to see that $\hat F(U) \subset V$.

Indeed, the orientation of $X$ induces an orientation on the open subset $F(U) \subset M$ such that the diffeomorphism $F \mid_U  : U \to F(U)$ is orientation preserving. If $[E_1^p, \ldots, E_n^p]$ is the orientation of $T_p X$ with $p \in U$, then $[\tilde E_1^{F(p)}, ..., \tilde E_n^{F(p)}]$  with $\tilde E_i^{F(p)} = dF_p(E_i^p)$ is the induced orientation on $T_{F(p)} F(U) = T_{F(p)} M$.

It follows from the construction of the orientation covering that the set $W =  \bigcup_{q \in F(U)} \left\{ (q, [\tilde E_1^{q}, ..., \tilde E_n^{q}]) \right\}$ is one of the two sheets over $F(U)$. But by definition of $\hat F$ we have

1. $\hat F (U) \subset W$
2. $W = V$ since $\hat F (p) = (q, [\tilde E_1^{F(p)}, ..., \tilde E_n^{F(p)}]) \in W$.

Comment: So I guess we pick an oriented frame $(E_1, ..., E_n)$ on $U$, then $(F_*E_1, ..., F_*E_n)$ is a continuous oriented frame on $F(U)$ (pushforward). Then $W$ as you've defined is the set $\widehat{U}_{\mathcal{O}}$ (Lee's notation) where $\mathcal{O}$ is the orientation $[dF_p(E_1^p), ..., dF_p(E_n^p)]$, which is equal to $V$ since they are connected components with common points.

Comment: @TobErnack This is correct.